# Null when sharing data between Activity and Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I got a problem that I can't share a RxBleClient between MainActivity and Fragments.
I pass a instance of RxBleClient to MyViewModel, and while trying to receive from ViewModel in Fragment it is just a Null. Fragment is a part of ViewPager2. Here is how I did this:

View Model code:

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<RxBleClient> rxBleClient = new MutableLiveData<RxBleClient>();

    public MyViewModel() {
    }

    public void setRxBleClient(RxBleClient item) {
        rxBleClient.setValue(item);
    }

    public LiveData<RxBleClient> getRxBleClient() {
        return rxBleClient;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        MyViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);

        //        Turn on Bluetooth
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
        this.startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

//        pass instance of RxBleClient to ViewModel
        rxBleClient = RxBleClient.create(getApplicationContext());
        model.setRxBleClient(rxBleClient);
// bind
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
// rest of code
```

Fragment code:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connection_list, container, false);
        scanResultList = new ArrayList<ScanResult>(0);
        // Set the adapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyConnectionRecyclerViewAdapter(scanResultList));
        }

        // get View Model
        myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);

        myViewModel.getRxBleClient().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), client -> {
            this.rxBleClient = client; // HERE IS NULL
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Where did I make mistake?

---

First edit:

This is my only one Activity, yet. This Activity is hosting ViewPager2:

```
//        FRAGMENT ADAPTER
        fragmentStateAdapter = new ViewPager2FragmentStateAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(fragmentStateAdapter);

        // TOP BAR
        final String tabTitles[] = {"Debugging", "Bluetooth", "Video"};
        final @DrawableRes int tabDrawable[] = {R.drawable.ic_bug_report_24px, R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_24px, R.drawable.ic_videocam_24px};
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2,
                (tab, position) -> tab.setText(tabTitles[position]).setIcon(tabDrawable[position])
        ).attach();
```

Comment: hi are you sure you don't pass a null client in `model.setRxBleClient(rxBleClient);`

Comment: Yes, I am sure about that. Here is a proof: https://i.imgur.com/vQYKQuq.png (debug)

Comment: Are you sure this the `Activity`  which is hosting the viewpager and the Fragments ?